Potential Energy in a Block due to Shear Stress
[Illustration of the condition]
Consider a block of modulus of rigidity $n$ and surface area $A$. A tangential force $F$ is applied over the block keeping the lower surface fixed. The block shows a shear strain and bends by an angle $\phi$.
Let's say on application of a further Force $F$ the block bends further by angle $\mathrm{d}\phi$ and hence the upper portion of the block moves by $\mathrm{d}s = n \mathrm{d}\phi$
Thus $\mathrm{d}W = F\cdot \mathrm{d}s \Rightarrow \mathrm{d}W = F\cdot n\mathrm{d}\phi $.
Since $F= n \phi A$:
$$\mathrm{d}W = n\phi A\cdot n\mathrm{d}\phi$$
Since this work is stored as potential energy:
$$ \mathrm{d}U = n\phi A\cdot n\mathrm{d}\phi$$
Integrating with limits of $\phi$ from $0$ to $\Phi$ we get:
$$U/V = (n\Phi)(\mathrm{d}\Phi)/2$$
i.e. Potential Energy Density = $1/2$ Stress $\times$ Strain, where $V$ is the volume of the block.
Now, my query is, why did we take $F = n \phi A$ even if the force is larger than that? The block still would not move and hence its kinetic energy would be zero and thus all the work by $F$ would be stored as potential energy.

Write out your equations for the components of the stress- and strain tensors.

In general, potential energy stored in an isotropic elastic solid reads
$$U = \frac{1}{2} \int_V \varepsilon \hspace{-3pt} \varepsilon : \sigma \hspace{-4pt} \sigma \ ,$$
begin $\varepsilon \hspace{-3pt} \varepsilon$ and $\sigma \hspace{-4pt} \sigma$ the strain and the stress tensors, respectively.
From your picture, in a 2-dimensional problem, the displacement field reads
$$\begin{cases}
d_x(x,y) = \frac{D}{H} \, y \\
d_y(x,y) = 0 \ , \\
\end{cases}$$
being $D$ the horizontal displacement of the upper wall, $H$ the height of the solid. The Cartesian coordinates of the strain tensor read
$$\varepsilon_{ij} = \frac{1}{2} \left( \partial_j u_i + \partial_i u_j \right) = \begin{bmatrix} d_{x/x} & \frac{1}{2} \left( d_{x/y} + d_{y/x} \right) \\  \frac{1}{2} \left( d_{x/y} + d_{y/x} \right) &  d_{y/y} \end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix} 0 & \frac{D}{2H} \\ \frac{D}{2H} & 0 \end{bmatrix}$$
Only the non-diagonal components are non-zero, and the constitutive equation for an isotropic elastic medium links them with the off-diagonal components (shear) of the stress tensor as
$$\sigma_{ij} = 2 G \varepsilon_{ij} \quad , \quad \text{ for $i \ne j$} \ .$$
Thus, evaluating the product under the integral, we get
$$\varepsilon \hspace{-3pt} \varepsilon : \sigma \hspace{-4pt} \sigma = \sum_{ij} \varepsilon_{ij} \sigma_{ji} = \varepsilon_{xy} \sigma_{yx} + \varepsilon_{yx} \sigma_{xy} = 2 \frac{D}{2 H} 2 G \frac{D}{2 H} = G \frac{D^2}{H^2} \ ,$$
and, performing the integral of the constant energy density, the potential energy stored in the solid reads
$$U = \frac{1}{2} G \frac{D^2}{H^2} H L \ .$$

I'm in my junior year and I'm not much aware of most of the terms you used in your answer.Could you please rectify according to my derivation?
